Unable to get expected result when performing relational queries using linkMany
I want to query a list of NoteCollectionEntity which does not contain a NoteEntity having an id of value id.
For context, here's the model definition for NoteEntity:
@Entity()
@CopyWith()
class NoteEntity implements BaseEntity {
  @Id()
  @override
  int id = BaseEntity.idPlaceholder;

  final String title;

  final String content;

  @Backlink(
    'notes',
  )
  final ToMany<NoteCollectionEntity> collections;

  NoteEntity({
    this.id = BaseEntity.idPlaceholder,
    required this.title,
    required this.content,
    required this.collections,
  });
}

Here's the model definition for NoteCollectionEntity:
@Entity()
@CopyWith()
class NoteCollectionEntity implements BaseEntity {
  @Id()
  @override
  int id = BaseEntity.idPlaceholder;

  final String name;

  final ToMany<NoteEntity> notes;

  NoteCollectionEntity({
    this.id = BaseEntity.idPlaceholder,
    required this.name,
    required this.notes,
  });
}

This is what I've tried:
final box = await bloc.repository.noteCollectionBox;
final builder = box.query()
  ..linkMany(
    NoteCollectionEntity_.notes,
    NoteEntity_.id.notEquals(
      note.id,
    ),
  );
final query = builder.build();
final collections = query.find();
query.close();
print('collections: $collections');
for (final collection in collections) {
  print('collection: ${collection.name}');
}

The query result returned on query.find() contains only those note collections whose notes property is non-empty. Also it does not contain that particular note provided as input to the query, which is what I want. But the problem here is that the note collections whose notes property is empty are not present in the query result.
I'm confused about whether this is a bug in ObjectBox or if there is a problem in what I've tried above.
I need help.

Thanks for reporting! I'll try to reproduce this.

I could reproduce this, thanks again! I created an internal issue for this and I'll get back to you if this by design (in which case we should update docs) or a bug.
